# Detecting and fixing corrupted indeces in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Today I encountered a case where a record was missing in query result while existed in the table. I traced back the problem to probably a corrupted index. After I did `REINDEX` the problem was solved.

The thing is that normally when I run reports I get more than a 10000 records. It is impossible for me to know if there are missing records. Today I was lucky to find the problem.

Is there a way to get a notification when an index is corrupted?

If not, how do I write a function that will `REINDEX` all indeces in my Schema?

Comment: Which **exact** Postgres version are you running?

Comment: I run postgresql 9.3

Comment: That's not the **exact** version. There are 10 different releases for 9.3. What does `select version()` give you?

Comment: There were numerous bug fixes after 9.3.3., especially one in 9.3.4 that would prevent index corruption. You should really use the latest version.

Comment: thx but it's not my call when to upgrade... i'm looking for a more immideate solution...

Comment: Some [approaches to detect corruption](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption#Detecting_corruption) are listed in PostgreSQL wiki. For example, `amcheck` module is [used by Heroku](https://help.heroku.com/V01BV4NT/postgres-index-corruption-faq).

Answer (score 1):

Index corruption is very bad problem. I think you need to diagnose and fix this fundamentally and not try to band aid it in your query. It might be caused by poor administrative actions like `kill -9` of any of `Postgres` processes etc.

To your question: there is no verifier tool AFAIK. I believe that a query that scans the whole index e.g. sort on index will find damaged pages in indeces.

I recommend you to read [this blog](http://blog.ringerc.id.au/2012/10/avoiding-postgresql-database-corruption.html).

Comment: How do I write such query?  The thing is that when runing a query I get results.. It seems more a problem of the record wasn't indexed properly rather than it was there and then lost... It was a new record...

Comment: But how do you **proactively** detect corruption without some form of tool?