# Postgresql Select based on primary key return null

Tags: postgresql, orm

So I found a bizarre error in my apps, and I still don't know why and what causes this.
So I have attached 3 pictures. The first picture is the query result in beaver, using *seeds_tag* to search for a user. I found the bugged user and found its ID **27820**.

In the second picture, I query using ID **27820**, but it returns nothing. The third picture I query using *BETWEEN* ID 27817 to 27822 shows another number except **27820**. Can anyone explain what happened with the **id column**? it broke my app because my ORM or Postgres query couldn't find that ID while my app used ID as a user identifier.
*ID column is primary key, autoincrement bigint.*

[image: Query by Seeds_tag]

[image]

[image]

Comment: **1.** Is it still visible when you search for it using the `seeds_tag` again? Could it have been deleted after your first query? **2.** Is it a table, a view, a materialized view, partitioned table, does it have triggers on it, is it maintained by a standby process/daemon/cron job? **3.** Do you run these queries within the same session, as the same user, in separate transactions? **4.** Do you get the same behaviour when interacting with this structure using a different client, psql, PGAdmin, your app's client library? **5.** Have you checked `pg_stat_activity` table to see DBeaver's query?

Comment: 1. I'm already checking it multiple times, and it is still there. I tried searching using another unique column (email & phone), and it still returned the result.
2. It is a table don't have any trigger and no cron
3. Same session and same user, different transactions.
4. Checked with Dbeaver, pgadmin 4, prisma ORM, same result
5. I don't have access to it.

Comment: tried select sorting it by updated_at or search by any other column show no problem.
But when selecting based on ID, the rows seems invisible from postgres.

Comment: Perhaps this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798633/detecting-and-fixing-corrupted-indeces-in-postgresql

Comment: Nice info
I will update with the fix if there any

Thank you